Proving $\int\limits_{Q} u^2 dx ≤ C(n) \int\limits_{Q} (u^2_{x1} + · · · + u^2_{xn}) dx$ over a cube $Q$
I am trying to solve the following question:
Let $u(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ be a differentiable function on the closed unit cube
$Q$ defined by $0 ≤ x_1 ≤ 1$, . . . , $0 ≤ x_n ≤ 1$ and $u = 0$ on the boundary of the
cube. Prove that there is a positive constant $C(n)$ such that the inequality
holds for all such a function $u$.
$\int\limits_{Q} u^2 dx ≤ C(n) \int\limits_{Q} (u^2_{x_1} + · · · + u^2_{x_n}) dx$
I am thinking about it long time ago, and I still cannot prove it. I tried to use Green functions for $u^2$ and $u$ without any result. I tried using Cauchy Schwarz inequality, again without any result.

In one dimension we have by integration by parts $$\int_0^1 u(x)^2dx = \int_0^1 1\cdot u(x)^2dx=-\int_0^1 x 2u(x) u'(x)dx \leq 2 \int_0^1 \vert u(x)u'(x)\vert dx$$ where we used that $u$ vanishes on the boundary and $\vert x\vert \leq 1$. Cauchy-Schwarz gives $$ \leq 2 \left(\int_0^1 u(x)^2 dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 u'(x)^2  dx\right)^{1/2}.$$ Thus, dividing by the $L^2$ norm of $u$ and square both sides of the inequality yields $$\int_0^1 u(x)^2dx \leq 4 \int_0^1 u'(x)^2 dx.$$ Similar argument should work in higher dimensions.

Let $V(x)=x=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, then we get by the divergence theorem and the fact that $u$ vanishes on $\partial Q$
$$\int_Q u(x)^2dx = n^{-1} \int_Q u(x)^2 \text{div}(V)(x)dx =- \int_Q \nabla(u(x)^2)\cdot V(x) dx
=-2n^{-1} \int_Q u(x)(\nabla u)(x)\cdot x dx.$$
Using that $\vert x\vert\leq \sqrt{n}$ on our domain of integration, we get
$$\leq  2n^{-1/2} \int_Q \vert u(x)\vert \cdot \vert \nabla u(x)\vert dx.$$
Cauchy-Schwarz yields
$$ \int_Q u(x)^2 dx \leq 2 n^{-1/2} \left(\int_Q u(x)^2 dx\right)^{1/2} \left( \int_Q \vert \nabla u(x)\vert^2 dx\right)^{1/2}.$$
This implies the claim.

One possible proof would be via developing $u$ into its Fourier series and then using simple formula for second norm (so called Parselval's theorem). In case of $n=1$, say $u = \sum a_ke^{2{\pi}kx}$, then $\int u^2 = \sum |a_k|^2$ and $\int u_x^2 = \sum k^2|a_k|^2$ so the inequality follows. In general case one uses induction or $n$ dimensional orthogonal system.

Could you elaborate more please? I did not get it. Thank you!

What you did not get? Do some reading on Fourier series please. This is all simple stuff.

Seems like a bit of a heavy machinery to prove this.
